# Is that possible to initialize all the tenants DB at once and take all the records in a table? Laravel Multi tenant

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, multi-database

[image]

As my diagram, I want to get all the records of **table 1** in every tenants from the central domain side. Is that possible to initialize all the tenants at once and take all the records?

Or should I initialize tenants one by one and push records to an array?

I am using the tenancyforlaravel (archtechx/tenancy) package

**Updated 1**

In tenancyforlaravel tenancy package has a feature to connect tenant DB.It is called initialization. Normally It automatically identifies the database and initializes it by domain address. Also can manually initializes but need to give tenant id. [Source link](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/manual-initialization)

Comment: In your context, what do you mean by initializing?

Comment: Sorry. In the archtechx/tenancy package, it is like a connecting to DB. I will update my question with more details wise. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figure out how to do that after long days. It is very very easy with this package. There is a helper function. Only need to use this **runForMultiple** helper function. below has the example code,

```
tenancy()->runForMultiple(null, function (Tenant $tenant) {
        
        foreach (Product::get() as $product) {
            array_push($this->products, [
                'shop_id' => $tenant->id,
                'shop_name' => $tenant->name,
                'id' => $product->id,
                'name' => $product->name,
            ]);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Should definitively be in the documentation, thanks for this!